# KeyError when applying lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm am trying to apply a lambda function with an elif condition as I saw in tutorials like this one https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-use-if-else-elif-in-lambda-functions/

I am trying to find subscribed users to a service in level 1 or level 2 of subscription and also users that are not subscribed. As far as I understand, this code will search for users in list 1, if it does not find any, it will look for in list 2 and if it does not find any it will say it is an unsubscribed user. I don't understand why I am getting a KeyError here

```
search_column = 'user_name'
user_accounts_1 = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']
user_accounts_2 = ['user4', 'user5', 'user6']

types = {
        'subscribed_l1': 'subscribed_l1',
        'unsubscribed': 'unsubscribed',
        'susbcribed_l2': 'susbcribed_l2'
    }


df = df.assign(user_type=df.apply(
            lambda x: types['subscribed_l1'] if x[search_column] in user_accounts_1
            else (types['subscribed_l2'] if x[search_column] in user_accounts_2 else types['unsubscribed'])), axis=1)
```

The error

```
*** KeyError: 'user_name'
```

The column exists in df.columns

```
Index(['id', 'user_name', 'full_name'])
```

Comment: as an aside, you really should just define a function with a full function definition statement, there's like zero utility to using a lambda expression here

Comment: Is your lambda split over two lines?

Comment: @JonSG That seems to be OK since they're not getting a syntax error.

Comment: Anyway, when you `.apply` to a pandas dataframe, by default, it provides the *columns) as arguments. You need `axis=1` in the `.apply`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Scroll right, he has that.

Comment: You're just applying a *function*. There is no significant difference between `function` objects created by a `def` statement and those created by lambda expressions.

Comment: @Barmar to the *`.apply`* not to `.assign`... a great example of why this horrible expression shouldn't exist in the first place

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga So he was trying to do it correctly, he just misplaced the argument. It's basically a typo.

Comment: @Neither, Why call out Barmar then perpetuate the faux pas by assigning them a gender?

Comment: @JonSG quotes have meanings sometimes

Comment: @Neither So I can be intentionally offensive as long as I quote it? Nice. glad we got that out of the way.

Comment: @JonSG you can be offensive to me, yes. Not sure about the other people.